# Heroku won't accept push due to submodule

Tags: php, git, heroku, github, sendgrid

I've created a PHP app on heroku, and I installed the sendgrid-php submodule. However, when I try to push it, this occurs:

```
$ git push heroku
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Git submodules detected, installing
       Submodule 'sendgrid-php' (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) registered for path 'sendgrid-php'
       warning: templates not found /app/vendor/share/git-core/templates
       Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/build_wfcgkfb0p50x/sendgrid-php/.git/
       fatal: reference is not a tree: 3f145137608a98b09eb01d447ff9d31d161ef2a2
       Unable to checkout '3f145137608a98b09eb01d447ff9d31d161ef2a2' in submodule path 'sendgrid-php'
 !     Heroku push rejected, Submodule install failed with exit code 1

To git@heroku.com:gausschain.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I've also configured the SendGrid addon for Heroku. Any ideas as to how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

That means in actual submodule

SHA1 - 3f145137608a98b09eb01d447ff9d31d161ef2a2

has not been pushed yet. but in .gitmodules file this SHA is recorded on that specific branch

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're actually doing something wrong.  The recommended way to install the SendGrid PHP library is using composer.  You should have a look at the README for details on doing that.

There is a PHP Heroku Buildpack that has composer support.  Here is a tutorial to get you started:

http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/using-composer-manage